# Error while trying to remote login to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I've recently set up a MySQL server on my remote machine, I can easily use it when I'm connected to this machine, but I can't login to the server from a remote computer.

```
$ mysql -u antoine -p -h my_server_ip_address
```

results in this error:

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'MY_USERNAME'@'my_computer_public_ip'

Here is some things that could be interesting to you :

```sql
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE User='MY_USERNAME';
+-------------+------+
| User        | Host |
+-------------+------+
| MY_USERNAME | %    |
+-------------+------+

mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+-----------------------+----------------+
| USER()                | CURRENT_USER() |
+-----------------------+----------------+
| MY_USERNAME@localhost | MY_USERNAME@%  |
+-----------------------+----------------+
```

With this `$ mysql -V` i obtain this `mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

A part of my `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` looks like this :

```
bind-address            = my_server_ip_address
#skip-networking
```

Also here a sample of my firewall :

```sh
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Things i tried that didn't worked :

- changing the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 or commenting it and/or uncommenting the skip-networking
- This SQL query to change to my ip :

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
SET Host = 'my_computer_public_ip' 
WHERE User = 'MY_USERNAME';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and solved it like this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Seams that new version change it's policy of security. You need to do it like their way.

Quote content from link as following:

```
mysql_secure_installation
# do as it requires

mysql

mysql> SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user; 

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

mysql> CREATE USER 'sammy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sammy'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```